# PHP Sessions issues while on server but no on localhost

Tags: php, session, localhost

I'm passing the user variable through sessions. It works fine on the localhost but once on the web server it does weird things.

After logging in, the session variable works as should.....until you click on about three pages and it suddenly goes POOF!

Notice the "`Welcome, jordan.`" as opposed to the "`Welcome, .`" Also the top left corner.

Session functioning: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/32/loggedins.png/

Session POOF!
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/loggedinno.png/

Login/Create session variable code:

```
<?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        if (isset($_POST['user']))
        {
        $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
        $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
        if (preg_match($txtMatch,$user))
        {
        if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
        {
        $error = "Please enter all required fields";
        }
        else
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmembers WHERE user='$user'";
        $result = queryMysql($query);
        $rank = mysql_result($result, 0, 'rank');
        if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
        {
        $error = "Username does not exist.";
        }
        else
        {
        $getPass = mysql_result($result, 0, 'pass');
        $salt = substr($getPass, 0, 64);
        $hash = $salt . $pass;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) 
        {
        $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
        }
        $hash = $salt . $hash;
        if ($hash == $getPass)
        {
        if ($rank != "Banned")
        {
        $userLow = strtolower($user);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userLow;
        $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
        echo <<<_END
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        _END;
        echo "Successfully logged in. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to continue.";
        }
```

Header Code:

```
        <?php //gtheader.php
        session_start();
        include_once 'gtfunctions.php';
        $loggedIn = FALSE;

        if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        if ($user) echo "Current User: $user<br />";
        else echo "Current User: None<br />";
        $rank = $_SESSION['rank'];
        $loggedIn = TRUE;
        echo "is set SESSION['user']? Yes";
        }
        else echo "is set SESSION['user']? No";

        echo "<div id='header'><a class='header' href='index.php'> <h1 id='headerTitle'>$appname</h1></a>";
        if ($loggedIn == TRUE)
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmessages WHERE recip='$user' AND status='0'";
        $result = queryMysql($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) $num = "";
        else $num = "[".mysql_num_rows($result)."]";
        if ($rank == 'Owner' || $rank == 'Admin')
        {
        echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a     class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header'     href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>] | <a class='header' href='gtadmin.php'>Admin</a><br />";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a     class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header'     href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>]<br />";
        }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Are you calling session_start anywhere?

Comment: @AdamPlocher probably, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Not true. Php.ini has this setting: session.auto_start = 1

Comment: `session_start` isn't shown in what you posted. Could be the culprit. Give it a try `with` session_start(); see what that does.

Comment: `session_start();` is on your 2nd line of header code, should be on top; and of both files.

Comment: gtheader.php is called in every file. Including gtlogin. To call it in login.php would cause an error for a double session.

Comment: And even on line one as opposed to line two doesnt change anything. And it shouldnt.

Comment: @user2058050 Just a note: I noticed that you have 10 opening braces and 4 closing braces in your `Login/Create session variable code:` do they carry over to another file or is there something I don't know about (yet)?

Comment: No they are all closed I just didnt bother posting them as they dont effect the issue. Both pages continue down but dont affect sessions.

Comment: If you notice in the top left, when the user isnt set the test for isset($_SESSION['user']) is yes, even after the variable shows nothing.

Comment: You should put `session_start();` before your include file in header.php. There maybe a weird character in that file that probably is causing the output to be sent before `session_start()`. This can happen while uploading from windows to a Linux server sometimes. Since you mentioned it works fine on localhost

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ Not the issue. but fixed just in case.

Comment: @user2058050 The only thing that comes to mind for me is the `include_once 'gtfunctions.php';` - I must say that I'm not a `pro` but what if you tried `include 'gtfunctions.php';` instead? I'm picking at straws here of course.

Comment: gtfunctons doesnt work with sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The issue here is that Host Gator registers global variables. So since I use $user, and $_SESSION['user'] gets registered, it gets overwritten.

I fixed the issue by changing $_SESSION['user'] in all files to $_SESSION['myUser']

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in one environment and not the other, I'm guessing your PHP.ini has `session.auto_start = 1` in the environment that works.  Best practice is to always call `session_start()` at the top of your page and not rely on `php.ini` to be set correctly.  This should make it work in any environment.

Comment: session_start was in the code but didnt appear in the text. See top of 'header.php'

Answer (score 0):

Must call `session_start()` at the top of the page

**gtheader.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'gtfunctions.php';
    $loggedIn = FALSE;
    .....
```

Comment: Fixed and still broken. Not the issue.